# Extraer elementos de un string

Tags: python

Tengo una columna de un dataframe cuyo nombre es `dataCampo_1['RFID']`. La columna se ve algo así:

```
1       54000006003
2       54000008972
3       54000025236
4       54000011777
5       54000012136
           ...     
5736    54000024838
5737    54000024855
5738    54000025021
5739    54000025050
5740    54000025106
Name: RFID, Length: 5740, dtype: object
```

Necesito poder extraer los últimos cuatro elementos de esta serie. La particularidad es que algunos datos de cada fila no tienen la longitud de 11 como los que se ven en el print(). Es decir, algunos tienen una longitud de 3 o 4 caracteres.

Como podría hacer un bucle que me permita recorrer toda la columna y extraer estos elementos?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y muestra como sería el resultado que esperas.

Comment: Por ejemplo, si tienes 54000025106 quieres solo el 5106?

Comment: Si, así es es! Justamente eso necesito. Quizás es muy sencillo, pero estoy trabado en eso!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una respuesta usando `apply` en el dataframe:

```
print(dataCampo_1['RFID'].apply(lambda x: x[-4:]))
```

Lo que haces es aplicar en la columna el `columna[-4:]` que bien indicó RedSalas. Si quieres añadirlo como una columna extra a tu dataframe, sería simplemente:

```
dataCampo_1["Nueva columna"] = dataCampo_1['RFID'].apply(lambda x: x[-4:])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!

Me ha servido muchisimo este código. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar `[-4:]` para tomar los ultimos 4 digitos de cada cadena, un ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
sample_str = "54000025106"
# Toma los ultimos 4 carácteres
last_chars = sample_str[-4:]
print('4 digitos : ', last_chars)
```

En tu bucle cuando recorras tu serie *sample_str* será igual al valor que leerá de ahí (540000XXXXX), solo utiliza `[-n:]` donde n será la cantidad de caracteres finales que necesitas tomar.